# Тесты производительности. Серверные языки. СУБД

Tags: база-данных, сервер, производительность

Затеял стартап своими руками. Конечно, хочется сделать все по максимуму круто.
Не могу найти в сети толковой информации о сравнении серверных языков (платформ) типа `php, ruby, pyton` и т.д.

В первую очередь? Посмотрел бы на тесты производительности, но и любой другой анализ и сравнения были бы интересны.

Так же интересуют статьи по сравнению для СУБД.

Укажите направление, дайте ссылок.

Comment: - [C10k (Проблема 10000 соединений) на разных языках/платформах](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145796/)

Comment: Spectre, круто, спасибо огромное.

Comment: @Стас Казанин, только учтите, что тема сравнения производительности *крайне неоднозначная*.

К большинству оценок надо подходить с осторожностью. 

--

Для примера, **сами** попытайтесь определить время, которое затрачивается на *чтение таймера* (в т.ч. таймера виртуального времени потока в linux). Только проведите достаточно измерений.

Гарантирую, Вы будете удивлены результатами исследования.

--

Про чтение/запись с диска (особенно по сети) я уже не говорю.

Comment: @avp, Да, я понимаю что тут нужно очень много результатов, очень много данных что бы сделать какие то выводы, вот я их и ищу.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, тут задача исследованиями выяснить недостатки и преимущества систем и выбрать оптимальный софт что для меня очень важно. ASM это тру, можно нанять 50 олдовых разрабов и замутить хайспид проект :)
Ни одной темы без тролинга не обсудить ) Кстати, возможно реальные факты и правда пойдут в прок холиварам, почему бы нет :))

Comment: @Стас Казанин, Вы ведь понимаете, что сформулировали вопрос очень широко. 

Любой язык, любая СУБД имеют свою нишу (в которой их использовать более правильно (с учетом опыта исполнителей)).

Какая задача стоит перед Вами и какими ресурсами Вы располагаете можно только догадываться.

Хотите конкретных ответов, задавайте конкретные вопросы с достаточными входными данными.

Comment: @avp, Да, я понимаю, мне бы подошли любые сравнения и исследования по платформам и субд, мне нужно направление, дальше я бы мог разбираться сам. А конкретные вопросы скорее всего не дадут точные ответы, очень много конкурирующего софта. Скажем так, исходные данные это веб проект конечно же ориентированный на хайлод, в целом все. Просто хочется производительности понимаете )

Comment: [Вот здесь](http://www.spec.org/) серьезно занимаются вопросами производительности (в целом).

Comment: @Стас Казанин - видимо вам действительно *просто захотелось* производительности. У человека, который знает что делает столь абстрактных вопросов не возникает.

Фраза "это веб проект конечно же *ориентированный на хайлод*" тоже, несколько смущает.

 - "Так же интересуют статьи по сравнению для СУБД."
 - "Укажите направление, дайте ссылок, буду признателен."

[Вот](http://google.com) вам направление

PS: @Spectre, тесты, на которые ведет предоставленная вами ссылка, мягко говоря - гавно =)

Comment: И [тут можно глянуть](http://www.udemy.com/blog/modern-language-wars/)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, только потому что там node.js отстаёт? жду от вас примера true-тестов=)

Comment: @Spectre, нет, не потому-что отстает. Собственно а в чем вообще их смысл? По факту - Earlang по умолчанию использует все возможность процессора, а node.js вертятся в одном потоке. По моему такого рода тесты похожи на цитаты из записок кепа.

Я просто, как-бы, имел опыт применение ноды в продакшине, так вот - нагрузки там были в значительно выше. Да, там использовался кластер ( не такой большой, к слову, всего 4 ядра ), но, можете мне поверить, того бреда, о котором там пишут - нет и близко. Не удивлюсь если такая-же ситуация и с Python, Go (и со всеми остальными собственно).

Comment: "Во время бенчмарка каждую миллисекунду запускается новый клиент. Раз в секунду каждый клиент отсылает сообщение с текущим временем на сервер, а сервер отсылает это сообщение назад." какое это имеет отношение к real world приложениям?

В общем-ваше дело, верить в них или нет,я лишь пишу о том, что знаю, что тесты гавно =)

Как по мне - использование в реально мире намного важнее такого рода тестов, не находите? Кстати, если поискать - для Java, Go и Node.js вы легко можете найти примеры удачного применения, которые никак не согласны с тем, что описано в тестах ( с тем что Erlang тру не спорю 

Comment: собстенно данный тест позиционирует себя как синтетический и не в коем случае не претендует на проэкцию его к реальным приложениям, потому что иначе проверить сферическую производительность технологий в вакууме невозможно, а как синтетический тест он очень даже ничего. я это к чему, к тому, что с прямыми руками на любой технологии(естественно заточенной под это) можно добиться требуемого результата для хайлоад проекта.

Comment: @Spectre - я имел введу абсолютно то-же самое.

Ну вы сами написали - "с прямыми руками на любой технологии(естественно заточенной под это) можно добиться требуемого результата", тесты говорят об обратном, если верить им, то Go, Node.js, Python - вообще гавно и даже руки не помогут. Я ( и не только я ) так, мягко говоря, не считаю, посему тест гавно :D

Comment: >В первую очередь? посмотрел бы на тесты производительности

что ТС хотел, то я ему и предложил

>тесты говорят об обратном, если верить им, то Go, Node.js, Python - вообще гавно и даже руки не помогут

тесты скорее говорят, что криво написаннное приложение на Erlang будет работать быстрее криво написанного приложения на Go, Node.js, Python

Comment: @Spectre, Вы сами-то в этих тестах разобрались?

Я посмотрел только на хабре, в гит разбираться даже не полез, т.к. из хабровского текста рисуется картина, что *меряется неизвестно что и как*, а также непонятно кем. IMHO бред.

На каком количестве машин запускаются клиенты? Как обеспечивается 1ms интервал  запуска клиентов? Какие характеристики LAN? Что за сервер? И куча подобных вопросов. 

Обсуждение соответствует.

Answer (score 1):

"По-максимуму круто" - это правильно составленное ТЗ (включая SLA), а также соответствующая этому ТЗ архитектура. Бесполезно сравнивать БД или языки, не зная задачи. Это может быть как Erlang, так и Java, так и Python, так и Oberon, так и Си - в зависимости от требований к безопасности и верифицируемости кода, требованиям к железу, производительности, поддерживаемости, наличия и стоимости трудовых ресурсов и т.д. "Серебряных пуль" нет - у всего есть не только плюсы, но и минусы. Надо сначала определяться с требованиями и критериями, а уже потом сравнивать по ним варианты. Без этого вопрос про сферического коня в ваккууме. Та же производительность - Вам какая критична производительность - чтения, записи, выборки? На каком объеме данных? Без понимания ситуации даже ответ на этот вопрос не однозначен